# Empty service still causes ANR

Tags: android, android-service, android-anr-dialog

I've been getting an ANR on my app, and I'm having a lot of trouble finding out why.

The error is reproduced by launching my app, and then doing nothing, or pressing the sleep button. 20 seconds after the sleep, the app will have frozen. The ANR message is displayed when the phone is reawakened.

I've narrowed it down to this:

```
Intent startGCM = new Intent(getBaseContext(), GCMService.class);
startGCM.setAction("CONNECT");
startService(startGCM);
```

These lines are run as part of my main activity's startup(onCreate) routine. If I comment them out, the error is gone and the phone can sleep/wake as desired, and the app will still work.

You will recognize it as a very simple service call. So I looked at the target service, **and gutted the entire code of the onStartCommand() function**. There's no code running at all, apart from the return statement. But it doesn't stop the error from occurring.

I've found the traces.txt file on the phone, but there's no mention of any of my code. Here's the first bit of the main thread dump, probably also familiar:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4127f508 self=0x40f469a0
  | sysTid=12711 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074286384
  | schedstat=( 1176280531 686300303 3448 ) utm=93 stm=24 core=0
  #00  pc 0000da70  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
  #01  pc 00014899  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
  #02  pc 00014b01  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*,         void**)+104)
  #03  pc 000634f3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so     (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
  #04  pc 0001deb0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  #05  pc 0004d103  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
  #06  pc 000272e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #07  pc 0002bbe8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
```

Any clues? It makes no sense to me that anything is being waited for. Is there another file that says what it is waiting for?

Comment: Do you return START_STICKY from onStartCommand() ?

Comment: No, I just put in an integer. I'll look up this START_STICKY thing.

Comment: Ok. If you want your service to keep running until explicitly stopped , you need to return START_STICKY.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Perhaps I should have read the documentation better. I assumed something called "Service" would hang around.

Comment: Ok Good. Yeah , Also look at the service class , it provides required information